# Is that possible to reset select's timeout when it's being blocked?

Tags: c++

I've set the timeout to 60 secs,since some requires,the timeout needs to be reset after some events signalled to make sure select keep blocked.I've checked the msdn,it points 'When select returns, the contents of the TIMEVAL structure are not altered',this sounds that it is no use to modify the timeval when it's being blocking.My work enviroment is vs2010,what I can think of is implememnting a c++ timer by myself and use blocked wsa functions instead of non-blocked.But considered that these functions are in a thread,i'm not sure if it's going to be a problem.

Comment: Your question is (to me at least) very unclear.  Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible to reset select's timeout when it's being blocked?

No.

One technique that is employed is to add a private pipe to the FD set and send something down it when you want to interrupt the `select().`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make it clear,actually I maintain a websocket in a thread,and I set the select's timeout to 60 secs.If I received nothing during this time then I will close it,but if the event is signalled,I hope this timeout is set to 60 secs again and the select keep blocked.

Comment: The only way that you can know you received nothing during this time is by `select()` returning, so it isn't blocked at all. Unclear what you're asking.